# hz.conf missing in Angular when developing an Openstack Horizon plugin

Tags: django, angularjs, openstack-horizon

I wrote a quick plugin for Openstack Horizon that has **no javascript**. It worked fine in Icehouse I believe, but in the newer versions of Horizon it produces this error:

**Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hz due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hz.conf due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'hz.conf' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

I don't have hz.conf and I don't have any javascript in my pages. my _scripts.html file is empty. My base.html overrides {% block css %} but no javascript blocks. What am I doing wrong? The plugin's code is https://github.com/piousbox/openstack_horizon_dashboard/tree/0.0.1 version 0.0.1 has this problem, version 0.0.0 does not.